# Pandas json_normalize function doesn't export to excel file correctly

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, json-normalize

I am using the json_normalize function but it's not correctly exporting JSON to the excel file you can see below.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = [
    'https://www.cbr.nl/web/show?id=289168&langid=43&channel=json&cachetimeout=-1&elementHolder=289170&ssiObjectClassName=nl.gx.webmanager.cms.layout.PagePart&ssiObjectId=285674&contentid=11764&examtype=B', 
]
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url=url).json()
    print(r)
    jn = pd.json_normalize(r)
    df = pd.DataFrame(jn)
    df.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace your code of `jn = pd.json_normalize(r)` to the following code in order to expand the list of nested json under column `examInformation` into separate rows:

Use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
jn = jn.drop('examInformation', axis=1).join(jn.explode('examInformation').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['examInformation']), axis=1))
```

Or use: [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for faster execution:

```
jn_exp = jn['examInformation'].explode()
jn = jn.drop('examInformation', axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame(jn_exp.tolist(), index=jn_exp.index))
```

**Result:**

See expanded `examInformation` info at the far right columns below:

```
print(jn)

  vehicleCategory       type     id             name        lat       lon  examInformationAllLocations.allAttempts  examInformationAllLocations.successfulAllAttemptsPercentage contactInformation.streetName contactInformation.houseNumber contactInformation.houseNumberExtension contactInformation.zipCode contactInformation.city contactInformation.website contactInformation.email contactInformation.phone1 contactInformation.phone2 contactInformation.kvk contactInformation.drivingSchoolNumber contactInformation.tradeAssociations lessonTypes.Theorieopleidingen lessonTypes.Beroepsopleidingen lessonTypes.Bijzonderheden lessonTypes.Praktijkopleidingen              cbrLocation cbrLocationShortName                                     cbrLocationLink  locationSuccessfulPercentage  drivingSchoolSuccessfulPercentage  firstAttempts  successfulFirstAttemptsPercentage  retakeAttempts  successfulSecondAttemptsPercentage
0               B  rijschool  11764  Rijschool Baron  51.694322  5.287478                                       81                                                           43                  Amperestraat                             28                                                             5223CV        'S-HERTOGENBOSCH                                                                                          06 44 30 30 81           743056970000                                 1666U0                                                                  []                             []                         []                              []       Examencentrum Tiel                 Tiel     /nl/service/nl/artikel/examencentrum-tiel-1.htm                            57                                100              0                                  0               1                                 100
0               B  rijschool  11764  Rijschool Baron  51.694322  5.287478                                       81                                                           43                  Amperestraat                             28                                                             5223CV        'S-HERTOGENBOSCH                                                                                          06 44 30 30 81           743056970000                                 1666U0                                                                  []                             []                         []                              []  Examencentrum Den Bosch            Den Bosch  /nl/service/nl/artikel/examencentrum-den-bosch.htm                            54                                 42             30                                 43              50                                  42
```